# using serializeArray, trying to insert from ajax multiple inputs, each with ID

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to submit an ajax call for a form where I have added functionality to dynamically add inputs to a form. My forms are created based on an array  loop so sometimes I just have one form, sometimes more.

Regardless, I'm able to dump the proper input values from each form with a console on the button, but I'm getting a 500 error on the ajax submit.

One issue is that if I have 4 inputs in the form, I'm dumping all 4 and then my one hidden input value 'tickerID', but I'm calling a sql insert where I need to insert each value with that hidden input value.

My console log for data right now is this:
[image]

but I need to insert these as

```
insert into ticker_content (ticker_id, content)
     values (1, 'one'), (1, 'two');
```

If that makes sense.

Here's my addticker.php that's being called for the insert:

```
$items = $_POST['Items'];
$tickerID = $_POST['tickerID'];

foreach ($items as $item){

    $addTicker = "
        INSERT INTO ticker_content (tickerID, content)
        values ('$tickerID', '$item');
     "
     $mysqlConn->query($addTicker);
}
```

So basically for every Items[] value, I need to insert with the same hidden field.

Here's my form and JS code for reference. The first JS block is mainly for the functionality of dynamically adding inputs, but the last JS block is the ajax using serializeArray();

```
<?php foreach($tickerDisplays as $key => $ticker):?>

    <form id="Items" method="post">   
        <label id="ItemLabel">Item 1: </label>
        <input type="text" name="Items[]"><br/> <!--form starts with one input-->
        <button type="button" class="moreItems_add">+</button> <!--button dynamically adds input, up to 10 per form-->

        <input type="hidden" name="tickerID" id="tickerID" class="tickerIdClass" value="<?php echo $ticker['ticker'] ?>"><!--hidden input used for tickerID-->
        <input type="submit" name="saveTickerItems" value="Save Ticker Items">  <!--submit button-->
    </form>

<?php endforeach;?>




<!-- This is the functionality for each form to click the '+' button and create new inputs -->
<script type="text/javascript">

$("button.moreItems_add").on("click", function(e) {
var tickerID = $(this).closest('form').find('.tickerIdClass').val(); //get value of hidden input for form
  var numItems = $("input[type='text']", $(this).closest("form")).length;
  if (numItems < 10) {
    var html = '<label class="ItemLabel">Item ' + (numItems + 1) + ': </label>';
    html += '<input type="text" name="Items[]"/><br/>';
    $(this).before(html);
    console.log(tickerID);
  }
});

</script>

<!-- This is the ajax call to send all filled out and created inputs from form along with the hidden input -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#Items").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $("#Items").serializeArray();
    console.log(data);

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "addticker.php",
       data: $("#Items").serializeArray(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       }
     });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$items = $_POST['Items']; 
$tickerID = $_POST['tickerID']; 
$value = "";
foreach ($items as $item){
    $value .= "('$tickerID', '$item'),";
}

$addTicker = "INSERT INTO ticker_content (tickerID, content)
    values {$value}";
$mysqlConn->query($addTicker);
```

Use this code